# How to "unplug" a bluetooth mouse

Tags: kubuntu, mouse, touchpad, bluetooth

OK, I've set my system to deactivate the touchpad when a mouse is plugged in...

and that works perfectly when I turn my bluetooth mouse on.

But, I can see no way to re-activate the touchpad other than rebooting the system. I've tried turning the bluetooth mouse off, disconnecting the bluetooth device and deactivating bluetooth altogether. But I just end up with no pointing device at all.

The touchpad decativates and reactivates perfectly with a wired mouse.

Any ideas? This is Kubuntu version 16.04

Cheers

Sam